# How does one create 2 buttons next to each other that are equal in width and height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create 2 buttons next to each that are equal, but they aren't when I run the app on the emulator although I've written the same `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, why? It looks like this [image: Not equal buttons]

I've used a relative layout, may that be the reason? Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="HJÆLP......"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="suggest"
    android:id="@+id/suggest"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="rate"
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/suggest"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/suggest"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_above="@+id/suggest"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"

    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_above="@+id/description" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:text="description"
            android:id="@+id/description"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is how it looks now with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="HJÆLP......"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@id/suggest">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="suggest"
        android:id="@+id/suggest"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="rate"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_above="@id/suggest"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"

    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_above="@+id/description" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:text="description"
            android:id="@+id/description"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCJuh.png)

Comment: Put the Buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout, and set their `layout_width`s to `0dp`, and `layout_weight`s to `1`.

Comment: @MikeM.s comment is good. I'll add something that might help you understand why your layout looks like it does. You've set both buttons to be 200dp wide so you expect them to be the same size. In order to fit two 200dp wide buttons beside each other the screen needs to be at least 400dp wide. It looks like this is a Nexus One, it's less than 400dp wide! The first button gets the space it needs, the second button can only get the space that's left over.

Comment: I've edited it, but why is the textview like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen width too small for both buttons to appear correctly. Only first button displayed at the full size, the other button forced to smaller size.

If you need these buttons to cover all screen width and be equal size, then put buttons in LinearLayout, set both buttons width to "0dp" and weight to "1":

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="suggest"
        android:id="@+id/suggest"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="rate"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or set buttons width to smaller value.

You need to read more about RelativeLayout,for example [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_relative_layout.htm) and [here too](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

Comment: Remember when using layout weight you should also set the relevant attribute to 0dp. So in this case each button should have `android:layout_width="0dp"` not `match_parent`

Comment: What if I want the buttons at the bottom of the layout?

Comment: See updated code example: just add alignParentBottom="true" to linearlayout and add it to your relative layout

Comment: But now it looks like this (have uploaded an image)

Comment: @Hudhud sure. This is because your scrollview is "above" your buttons layout. Add android:id to linearlayout and change layout_above line in scrollview to this id. As i can see, you need to study more about RelativeLayout.

Comment: But I want it to be above the my buttons layout, and what do I've to add? `android:id="@+id/suggest"` ?

Comment: @Hudhud You need to add correct properties (layout_above/layout_below) to all items in your RelativeLayout. I added some useful links to the answer. GL

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button 1"
        style="@style/AppTheme_new"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button 2"
        style="@style/AppTheme_new"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

> 

Answer (score -2):

android:layout_weight will give you proportional spacing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="BUTTON ONE"/>

   <Button android:layout_weight="1" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
           android:text="BUTTON TWO"/>

</LinearLayout>
```